# How does this function definition work in python?

Tags: python

I'm a newbie to Python, with a Java background. I came across the following function definition

```
def S(seq,i=0):
    print i
    if i==len(seq): 
        return 0    
    return S(seq,i+1)+seq[i]
```

What exactly does the `i=0` do here, is it re-initialised to 0 each time? Because I notice that the value of i is incremented .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It provides the *default value* for the second argument.

The function can be called with either one or two arguments. If it's called with one, the second argument, `i`, defaults to zero.

Comment: so that means that in this case `seq` will be a mandatory argument?

Comment: @KodeSeeker:  Yes, `seq` would be a mandatory argument.  Also, Python default arguments often trip up programmers coming from other languages.  Make sure you read [Default Parameter Values in Python](http://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm).